# Google sheet script to update cell value in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a code I found in another topic but so far I failed. I'm trying to find the corresponding row and update the last column in another google spreadsheet after updating the first column of another spreadsheet.

When the user selects "ready" in `ColC of spreadsheet X`, I need to look up the ID value in ColB on another `sheet (Y)`. Then I need to access spreadsheet Y and find the row that contains that same ID. Access the last column or `columnC (3)` and change the cell value to "ready".

**Here is what I have so far but I get the error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
```

**Can anyone help me fix this?**

```
    function onEdit(e){
    
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
      if( s.getName() == "Studio"){
    
           if ( (e.range.getColumn() == 2.0) && (e.range.getValue() == "ready") ){
    
            var nextCell = e.range.offset(0, -1);
            var buybackId = nextCell.getValue();
          
            var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bbNuH_GXbmNwMHk7Kjo0zAhD-QGwQqiva8_HJc3mgFY');
    
            var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName("Status"); 
    
            var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
            for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
              if(data[i][1] == buybackId){ 
    
                sheet.getRange((i+1), 3).setValue("ready");
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
```

**The table structure looks like this:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the 1st section of your question, you say `I'm trying to find the corresponding row and update the last column in another google spreadsheet after updating the first column of another spreadsheet.`. But, from your 2nd section, it seems that you wanted to run the script by editing column "B" like `ready`. By the way, about `When the user selects "ready" in ColC of spreadsheet X,`, your `selects` is to edit?

So, when column "B" in "Studio" sheet on the active Spreadsheet is edited to like `ready`, you want to update column "C" of "Status" sheet in another Spreadsheet by checking the ID of column "B".

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In order to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById`, it is required to use the installable OnEdit trigger.
- About your current error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')`, I'm worried that you might have directly run the function `onEdit` with the script editor. In that case, such an error occurs because of no event object.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, [please install OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). When you use this script, please edit the column "B" of "Studio" sheet of the active Spreadsheet. By this, the script is run. And, please set your destination Spreadsheet ID to `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');`.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Studio" || range.columnStart != 2) return;
  const [id, status] = range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).getDisplayValues()[0];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###'); //  Please set the destination Spreasheet ID.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Status");
  const r = dstSheet.getRange("B2:B" + dstSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(id).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!r) return;
  r.offset(0, 1).setValue(status);
}
```

- When this script is run by the installable OnEdit trigger, the above goal can be achieved.

#### Note:

- If you want to copy all values from the source sheet to the destination sheet, how about the following sample script? In this case, you can directly run the script with the script editor.

  ```js
  function sample() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Studio");
    const obj = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {});
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###'); //  Please set the destination Spreasheet ID.
    const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Status");
    const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("B2:C" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
    const dstValues = dstRange.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [obj[b] || c]);
    dstRange.offset(0, 1, dstValues.length, 1).setValues(dstValues);
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- About the 1st script, when you directly run the script, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. Please be careful about this. The 1st script is automatically run with the installable OnEdit trigger.
- By the way, when you use the 1st script, please rename your `onEdit` function name. Because when you didn't rename it, when the cell is edited, both functions `installedOnEdit` and `onEdit` are run. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

### Added:

About your new question of `How to modify it if I need to edit status in column C instead of column B in "Production sheet"?` and `I need it to be triggred by edit in column C sending data from column C.`, please modify the above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Studio" || range.columnStart != 3) return; // Modified
  const [id, , status] = range.offset(0, -2, 1, 3).getDisplayValues()[0]; // Modified
  Browser.msgBox([id, , status])
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###'); // Please set your Spreadsheet ID of destination spreadsheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Status");
  const r = dstSheet.getRange("b2:b" + dstSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(id).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!r) return;
  r.offset(0, 4).setValue(status);
}
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you! One more thing. How to modify it if I need to edit status in column C instead of column B in "Production sheet"?

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa About `It works perfect. Thank you!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa About your new question of `One more thing. How to modify it if I need to edit status in column C instead of column B in "Production sheet"?`, if you use my 1st script, when `const [id, status] = range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).getDisplayValues()[0];` is modified to `const [id,,status] = range.offset(0, -1, 1, 3).getDisplayValues()[0];`, is that your expected result?

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa If you had used my 2nd script, how about modifying `const obj = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {});` to `const obj = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [a,,c]) => (o[a] = c, o), {});`? If my understanding of your new question was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: I used first script and now the change is triggered when I edit column B and it sends data from colulm C. I need it to be triggred by edit in column C sending data from column C.

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. About `I used first script and now the change is triggered when I edit column B and it sends data from colulm C. I need it to be triggred by edit in column C sending data from column C.`, I have already proposed an answer to your new question. When you tested it what result did you obtain? If your issue is still not resolved, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: [link] (https://ibb.co/G0rdZWQ) Here is the structure of the table. I tried changing the variables in your code to reach desired result but I can't understand the dependencies between it.

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. About `Here is the structure of the table. I tried changing the variables in your code to reach desired result but I can't understand the dependencies between it.`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script? In the current stage, in order to correctly understand your new question, it is required to know the current Spreadsheet and script. Because I cannot know your current script. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa I think that the reason that I cannot understand your current script from your reply of `I tried changing the variables in your code to reach desired result but I can't understand the dependencies between it.` is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bbNuH_GXbmNwMHk7Kjo0zAhD-QGwQqiva8_HJc3mgFY/edit?pli=1#gid=0) [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ATy7FjKXgBQIeruMIoS1jlqGyepuf6YDou7fiBKnOMs/edit?pli=1#gid=0)

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet, I added a sample script for your new question. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa About `Thank you for your help. Everything works perfect.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad both your initial question and your new question were resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer